# CSS: Background with 2 colors, divided horizontally, with a pattern?

Tags: css

Here's what I have right now:

`background: #FFFFFF url("whitegrid.png") repeat left top;`

[Here's what I want to achieve.](http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_376_secured)

How do I achieve this split background effect, maintaining the repeating pattern on both colors, and making the top color only fill a fixed percentage (eg. 30%) of the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

may this help you :

[Use CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/%E2%80%8E)

but pay attention that this supports only in modern browsers

sometimes you can make 2 div like layers:

```
<div class="gradient">
    <div class="pattern">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't think 2 `div`s are needed for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/VpyRy/1/show/**

i am not sure if what you are asking is what i am understanding...but if it's as simple as it sounds then background is composed of two divs. You could use multiple backgrounds/images but divs are much easier and appropriate here. http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/32gPX/

```
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
html,body{width: 100%;height: 100%; position: relative;}
body { background-color: red;}
.nav {height: 50px; background-color: rgb(64, 47, 71);}
.main {
    width: 480px; padding: 40px; background-color: white; height: 400px; margin: auto; margin-top: 30px;
}

.white {
    background-color: orange; width: 100%; height: 200px; 
    position: absolute; top: 50px; z-index: -1;}
```

Comment: Well, it works but ... Absolute positioning an element for just background? Why not CSS gradient?

Comment: i guess both are fine...especially since that gradients are supported most of the places now.